# Password - Binary Modular Crypt Format

Tags: php, mysql, segurança

Encontro-me neste momento a reduzir o tamanho de uma base de dados e várias são as técnicas utilizadas. No entanto estou com uma dúvida na decisão a tomar num ponto e gostaria que alguém me conseguisse ajudar.

No modelo em questão e na tabela de utilizadores é utilizado uma password BCRYPT esta tem definido um tamanho de máximo de 60 bytes na base de dados. Sei que utilizando técnicas 
BMCF (Binary Modular Crypt Format ) posso conseguir reduções para 40 bytes... em detrimento do MCF que é o standard.

No entanto esta técnica adiciona mais um "layer" que no caso de passwords acho que vale a pena, não no sentido da segurança mas no trabalho de redução da base de dados.

Para um algoritmo em PHP estarei certo? Ou seja mais um "layer" sobre servidores de alta disponibilidade irá colocar alguma latência, mas se mantiver o atual MCF e tendo em conta que a password não é um campo de "INDEX" da base de dados será que vale mesmo a pena?

Conhecem  outras técnicas alternativas?

PS: Sei que existem outros além do BCRYPT mas isso eu não posso mudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por não ter obtido qualquer resposta à minha questão venho colocar qual a minha decisão esperando que a mesma seja útil para alguém.

O meu ponto de partida era reduzir o tamanho da base de dados que é repartida por vários SHARDS e que mesmo assim e pelo diagnóstico dentro em breve irá rebentar pelas costuras. Antes de colocar novo servidor e dividir os vários SHARDS pelos servidores, o meu esforço era o de reduzir o que fosse possível.

Muitos foram os aspectos considerados e após a minha análise, consegui em muitas tabelas uma redução perto de 33%... ou seja em tabelas de quase 1TB reduzir apenas com optimizações de campos e algumas alterações de código PHP inclusivé foi motivo para já ganhar um medalha... heheheh (desculpem o aparte)

No entanto faltava a tabela de utilizadores e aí após a luta deparei-me com o campo da PASSWORD. E foi então que na dúvida coloquei aqui a questão.

Reduzir um campo de 60 bytes de uma senha BCRYPT para 40 na realidade pode ser feito e o ganho numa análise simplista é de executar e nem olhar para trás.

No entanto este processo trazia alguns pontos negativos:

1. adiciona mais um layer ao sistema para a gravação e leitura
2. a gravação tem de acontecer num campo BINARY
3. O conteúdo deixa de ser um STANDARD

Ora, no caso o campo de PASSWORD não é um campo de index e quem lida com MYSQL sabe de alguns problemas que se obtem ao gravar campos em BINARY. Tendo já conseguido reduzir o tamanho do registo optei por apenas alterar um campo `VARCHAR(60)` para `CHAR(60) BINARY` e assim manter o standard tendo em conta que o BCRYPT...

1. é um processo já muito seguro e que o hash resultante é muito mais que um hash
2. a avaliação para saber se a senha precisa do re-hash é imediato após leitura sem
   precisar de mais um "layer"
3. o mesmo do ponto 2 mas para a obtenção do "salt"
4. a alteração de VARCHAR para CHAR parece-me óbvia e a TAG BINARY é apenas para que não seja considerada _bin de forma a não acontecer qualquer tradução de caracteres.

Espero ajudar outros quando confrontados com uma situação semelhante.

Conclusão mantive o tamanho!